# Django - Showing two table data on a page

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a table of lessons and exams. I list them by filtering according to the academicians. When I enter the content of the lesson, I see the data for the lesson. I want to see the exam information that belongs to the lesson on the lesson page and I cannot show it because there are different tables. Exams for each lesson: Mid-term and final exam. For example ; Mid-term exam, A, Final exam; Midterm exam for B, Final, Make-up exam.

models.py

```
def set_user_files_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join([
        'users', 'user_%d' % instance.id, 'images', filename
    ])

class Lesson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Ders Adı'), max_length=150)
    lesson_content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Ders İçeriği'), blank=True)
    lesson_content_file = models.FileField(
        verbose_name=_('Ders İçeriği Dosya'),
        upload_to=set_user_files_upload_path, blank=True, null=True
    )
    lesson_notes = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Ders Notu'), blank=True)
    lesson_notes_file = models.FileField(
        verbose_name=_('Ders Notu Dosya'),
        upload_to=set_user_files_upload_path,
        blank=True, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{lesson_name}'.format(
            lesson_name=self.lesson_name
        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Lesson'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Lesson'


class Exam(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam_type = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Sınav Türü'), max_length=50)
    exam_information = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Sınav Hakkında Bilgi'), max_length=500)
    exam_file = models.FileField(
        verbose_name=_('Sınav Kağıdı Dosya'),
        upload_to=set_user_files_upload_path, blank=True, null=True
    )
    exam_answer_file = models.FileField(
        verbose_name=_('Cevap Anahtarı Dosya'),
        upload_to=set_user_files_upload_path, blank=True, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{lesson} - {exam_type}'.format(
            lesson=self.lesson.lesson_name,
            exam_type=self.exam_type
        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Exam'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Exam'
```

views.py

```
class LessonListView(ListView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'edms/lesson/list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'lessons': lessons})


class LessonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'edms/lesson/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['lesson_list'] = Lesson.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['exam_list'] = Exam.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

Comment: can you share your template ?

Comment: what do you mean by "enter the content of lesson", do you mean when you "request for the lesson" ?

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh There are lessons in the database. Each one lesson belongs to an academician. Each lesson has three exams. I'm showing  the lesson information. But I can't show the exams

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FWWTc0cxyaBCIFg7-EjTMd4V8T6hDF3g)

Comment: you are passing "exam" in template but you did not give a context "exam" in your views .py

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh how should I do.

Comment: I am not getting what you want to do. As I am seeing your template you have passed <h1>{{ lesson.lesson_name }} </h1> "lesson" as the context but you have not specified it in views.py .

Comment: Is your data getting rendered for <h1>{{ lesson.lesson_name }} </h1> this template tag

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh <h1> {{lesson.lesson name}} </ h1> there is no problem in this section. The problem is that the {{exam.exam_type}} field does not return data.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh output picture this [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/17QZ0mdE4qhGgUzs2oDpSgf5W14TFb87v/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: in your views.py try to add this " exam = lesson.exam_set.all() ".

Comment: Thank You. Okkey